# Getting element attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have footer links on my website and I'm trying to get the `title` attributes of the anchor tag using the following method.

```
(function($){
    $("#block-footermenu a.nav-link").each(function(e) {
        console.log($(e).attr('title'));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

but in the console, I'm getting `undefined` what I'm missing here?

Following is my HTML

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-footermenu-menu" id="block-footermenu" class="block block-menu navigation menu--footer-menu">
    <ul class="nav ul_align">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" title="Sitemap" href="/us/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` to refer back to the element on which you have clicked.

```js
(function($){
    $("#block-footermenu a.nav-link").each(function(e) {        
        console.log($(this).attr('title'));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-footermenu-menu" id="block-footermenu" class="block block-menu navigation menu--footer-menu">
    <ul class="nav ul_align">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" title="Sitemap" href="/us/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```